# Por que las pruebas de ruby y rails son super lentas en linux?

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, ruby, test

He revisado blogpost desde el 2008 hasta la fecha. Herede un proyecto de ruby on rails para el cual debo incrementar el codigo de pruebas.

Trabajo en un equipo asus laptop 8gen cpu i7U con 16gb ram y un ssd de 512gb.

Inicialmente corria ubuntu 19.10, cuando comence el proyecto y las prueba, aproximadamente unas 1200, tardan mas de 1hr en correr.

Mientras que en una macbook pro del 2015 con 8gb de ram y un hdd, toma solo 2-3 min.

El log/test.log no reporta errores, las pruebas no se quedan colgadas pero es demasiado tiempo especialmente cuando incrementare la cantidad de pruebas.

Desinstale ubuntu, hice un wipe de ssd, instale solus, arch y ubuntu, mismo setup para todos a traves de asdf como manejador de versiones y en ninguna distro el tiempo es menor a 1hr.

Alguien sabe porque ocurre esto en linux? El setup de mac tambien es a traves de asdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta no es por qué "las" pruebas son lentas en Linux, sino que "tus" pruebas los son.
Podrías probar a agregar [`test-prof` usando `stackprof` como profiler](https://test-prof.evilmartians.io/#/stack_prof), correr una sola prueba y ver qué parte del código es la que se está demorando.
Como prueba un ejemplo. En un test con `rspec` que tengo creado, haré un `:focus` para solo ejecutar esa prueba y `:sprof` para hacer profiling con stackprof:

```
it 'is valid for positive hour', :sprof, :focus do
```

Si usas `minitest`, puedes probar a agregar `TestProf::StackProf.run` a un test específico que quieras ejecutar. Luego al correr los tests:

```
┗ rspec
Run options: include {:focus=>true}

JobDeadline
  validations
    deadline time
      for jobs
        [0.13s] is valid for positive hour
[TEST PROF INFO] StackProf report generated: tmp/test_prof/stack-prof-report-wall-raw-jobdeadline-validations-deadline-time-for-jobs-is-valid-for-positive-hour-1587373893.dump
[TEST PROF INFO] Run the following command to generate a flame graph report:

stackprof --flamegraph tmp/test_prof/stack-prof-report-wall-raw-jobdeadline-validations-deadline-time-for-jobs-is-valid-for-positive-hour-1587373893.dump > tmp/test_prof/stack-prof-report-wall-raw-jobdeadline-validations-deadline-time-for-jobs-is-valid-for-positive-hour-1587373893.html && stackprof --flamegraph-viewer=tmp/test_prof/stack-prof-report-wall-raw-jobdeadline-validations-deadline-time-for-jobs-is-valid-for-positive-hour-1587373893.html


Finished in 0.76698 seconds (files took 15.35 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Lo importante es la antepenúltima línea, que comienza con `stackprof --flamegraph`. Tendrás que ejecutarla en tu terminal, lo cual te generará una línea completa del tipo `file://` que debes copiarla y abrirla en tu browser. Al abrirla te cargará una página como la sgte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde podrás ver una línea de tiempo con el detalle de cada parte de lo que se ejecutó en tu test y cuánto se demoró.
De más está decir que esto no es una solución a tu problema, pero te ayudará a ver cual es la causa de la lentitud (supongo que pueda ser alguna gema que ha sido compilada usando librerías del sistema distintas a osx y por eso se comporta de manera distinta).
Si tienes problemas para interpretar la página resultante, sube a algún servicio el `.dump` generado en `tmp/test_prof`, o mejor aún el `.html`, en caso que hayas podido ejecutar `stackprof`, y puedo ayudarte en algo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Aunque agrego que al trabajar en una empresa dedicada al desarrollo de software somos muchos equipos trabajando diferentes aplicaciones con ruby que tenemos el mismo problema y no usamos mismas gemas o versiones. Sin embargo, tu respuesta ayuda y te agradezco. Comenzaremos por ahi para tratar de ver lo que ocurre. Lo unico malo es que vemos que no siempre se pone lenta en las mismas pruebas tiene un comportamiento aleatorii, por eso esperabamos fuera algo del sistema operativo

Comment: Personalmente no he tenido ese tipo de problemas. De hecho, en este momento me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto, el cual lo he corrido tanto en Osx como Ubuntu, sin alguna diferencia importante en los tiempos de ejecución de los tests. Ahh, y recuerda, si mi respuesta te fue util, recuerda marcarla como correcta. Saludos

Comment: https://github.com/alexzaizar09/sharingdocs Alter, aqui te dejo el dump y el html, si pudieras ayudarme lo agradezco, no tengo idea de que sigue. Use minitest reporters y esa prueba en particular es la más lenta de todo el sistema.

Comment: @alexzaizar09 según la información que envías, lo que mas está tomando tiempo en cada test es en el uso de [`json_matchers`](http://alagos.github.io/temp/flame.html) (use otro visualizador del dump). Quizás la información a procesar es mucha y por eso se demora más ¿quizás haya algún seed más liviano que esté disponible para testing en los equipos con osx y por eso se demora menos?. Te recomiendo hacer una nueva pregunta, donde pongas la info que te entrega por pantalla la ejecución del mismo test, tanto en linux como osx, junto con los dump resultantes, para apreciar mejor las diferencias.

Comment: Gracias, por el momento ya no tenemos tiempo para intentar soluciones, deberemos trabajar en mac porque en linux es imposible la espera del tiempo de ejecucion. Te agradezco y ojala se resuelva seria una lastima que hubiera un monopolio del mercado por esto. Mi percepcion es que los equipos aqui se quedaron con la idea de que para trabajar ruby necesitan mac y pues eso no deberia ser.

Comment: jaja, no creo lo de monopolio de mercado. Como te digo, esto es un problema particular de tu proyecto, llevo años trabajando con ruby en Linux, corriendo tests, y no me ha dado ese tipo de problemas de rendimiento. Saludos